# mysql OR clause respective to AND clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form for filtering/sorting database records.

I'm filtering posts by author, category, and tags. I'm using `AND` clause for author and category and `OR` clause for tags (multiple tags can be entered)

A query looks like this

```
SELECT *
FROM (`posts`)
WHERE `author` = 'dan'
  AND `category` = 'technology'
  AND `tags` LIKE '%ebook%'
  OR `tags` LIKE '%ipad%'
  OR `tags` LIKE '%apple%'
```

The query above returns posts that contain any tag searched regardless of the author or category.

I want to return posts containing tags `ebook, ipad, apple` only within the author name `dan` and category `technology`.

How is it possible to do so in mysql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the brackets around the or's

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    (`posts`) 
WHERE 
    `author` = 'dan' AND 
    `category` = 'technology' AND 
     ( `tags` LIKE '%ebook%' OR `tags` LIKE '%ipad%' OR `tags` LIKE '%apple%' )
```

Comment: P.S. In the US those are almost always called "parentheses", and "brackets" typically refer to "[" and "]" but are usually called "square brackets" to be precise.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`posts`)
WHERE `author` = 'dan'
  AND `category` = 'technology'
  AND (`tags` LIKE '%ebook%' OR `tags` LIKE '%ipad%' OR `tags` LIKE '%apple%')
```

because of order of operations, what you were doing was equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`posts`)
WHERE (`author` = 'dan' AND `category` = 'technology' AND `tags` LIKE '%ebook%')
   OR `tags` LIKE '%ipad%'
   OR `tags` LIKE '%apple%'
```